# How to connect primer tubing to non-laundry faucet?

Tags: plumbing, drains

The previous owner of my house didn't know what the trap primer tubing was when he installed an expensive kitchen faucet and stainless sink in the laundry room, so left the tubing dangling. Is there a trick to connect it without replacing the faucet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the diameter of the tubing, and I'm guessing it's not very large since it hardly needs to be, you might be able to install a saddle tap valve to the cold water line and the primer tubing to it.

Comment: You're right, it's small; 1/4" tubing -- the saddle valve will work, but I was sort-of hoping for an automatic priming.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to install a flow-through trap primer.  This is a device that feeds a small amount of water to the trap primer everytime the supply it is connected to runs.  One constraint is that it needs to be oriented correctly due to the air gap.

The one pictured is from [Watts](http://www.wattscanada.ca/pages/_products_details.asp?pid=731)

> Series A200 Flow-Through Trap Primers are used in commercial and residential applications to assure delivery of water to floor drain traps to prevent the evaporation of the water seal that protects a building or room from sewer gas fumes. It consists of a bronze body construction with a Celcon seat and disc. Available in threaded (Model A200) or union solder (Model A200S) connections. Minimum Supply Pressure: must exceed 25psi (172kPa), Maximum Supply Pressure: 125psi (8.6 bar).

[image: Flow-through trap primer]

Comment: I'm surprised no one knew about this (I asked 6 so-called pros).  That would have been a much simpler/cheaper solution.  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

After more research and asking different plumbers, the unanimous solution was to replace the faucet with a laundry type that had the correct fitting for the primer tube.